# listview and tabview in the same activity

Tags: android, listview, tabview

i'm struggling to get a listview and tabactivity working together. can somebody show me the correct way to get these two working together in 1 activity.xml file , but with 2 classes ( i think that is how it should work )

the layout as per below

```
________________________________________
|  _____    _____    _____    _____    |
| | btn |  | btn |  | btn |  | btn |   |
| |_____|  |_____|  |_____|  |_____|   |
|______________________________________|
|              |                       |
|              |                       |
|              |                       |
|    list      |     tab contents      |
|              |                       |
|    view      |                       |
|              |                       |
|   contents   |                       |
|              |                       |
|    here      |                       |
|              |                       |
|              |                       |
|              |                       |
|              |                       |
|              |                       |
|              |                       |
|              |                       |
|              |                       |
|              |                       |
|______________|_______________________|
|  ____  ____  |      |       |        |
| |NXT ||PRV | | TAB1 | TAB2  | TAB3   |
| |____||____| |      |       |        |
|______________|______|_______|________|
```

The layout code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="310dp" >

                 </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

            </FrameLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>


</RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginRight="203dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@android:id/textview_peoples"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxWidth="70dp"
            android:minHeight="60dp"
            android:minWidth="55dp"
            android:text="Prev"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxWidth="70dp"
            android:minHeight="60dp"
            android:minWidth="55dp"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_category_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Back" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_category_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_category_back"
        android:text="Search" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_category_ts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_category_search"
        android:text="TS" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_category_ts"
        android:text="Button" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="360dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_ppp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:background="@color/greyish"
            android:text="PPP"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried various examples from androidituts, and some listed here on stackoverflow, but simply cannot get them to work together. I need for both to display the contents. I can get them to work independantly if i change the class file , to either show the contents of the listview , or changed to show the tabviews.

the class code i'm using below for the tabview

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;



public class subCategories_peoples extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.category_peoples);


        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Tab for Config
        TabSpec personspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Person");
        personspec.setIndicator("Person");
        Intent personIntent = new Intent(this, Category_personActivity.class);
        personspec.setContent(personIntent);

        // Tab for Family
        TabSpec familyspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Family");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        familyspec.setIndicator("Family");
        Intent familyIntent = new Intent(this, Category_familyActivity.class);
        familyspec.setContent(familyIntent);

        // Tab for History
        TabSpec historyspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("History");
        historyspec.setIndicator("History");
        Intent historyIntent = new Intent(this, Category_historyActivity.class);
        historyspec.setContent(historyIntent);


        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(peoplespec); // Adding person tab
        tabHost.addTab(familyspec); // Adding family tab
        tabHost.addTab(historyspec); // Adding history tab


    }

}
```

The class code i'm using for the listview :

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.ListActivity;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class SavedSearches extends ListActivity
{

// defining array to store string resources
String[] various_peoples;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// storing string resources into Array
various_peoples = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.various_people);

// Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
(this,R.layout.category_peoples, R.id.textview_peoples,various_peoples));
}
}
```

The class code for the activity loading all the above as follows :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class subCategories extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.btn_subcategories);

        Button btn_SubCategories_PPP = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_SubCategories_PPP);
        btn_SubCategories_PPP.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), subCategories_peoples.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
                    })

                    ;

                }

}
```

ultimately, i need both the listview and tabview to work together, and if i select something different from the listview, it should load a new set of tab contents, but that i'll work on/attemp myself.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: *i think that is how it should work )* - it isn't how it should work. You'd need an activity with the layout you posted and in that activity, you would setup the adapter for the `ListView` and also the tabs. If you want to communicate between the list and the tabs then use fragments instead of activities as tabs(also, the `TabActivity` is deprecated for some time now).

Comment: Did you check this Tutorial? [Android Combining List & Tab View](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/android-combining-tab-layout-and-list-view/)

Comment: yeah, had a look at that tutorial, couldn't see it working for me though. I need a listview  and the tabs on its own whereas the tutorial implements the listview inside the tabview. my tabs will have static content in it, and each list item in the listview should change the tabs to new contents related to list topic. I tried separating the content of the said tutorial to see if it could help me, but giving me too many errors.

Comment: ok, so i managed to make it work...and tabactivity changed